# What's google web master tools for and how does it compare to google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

Does anybody know what google web master tools offer 
I have google analytics on and I just realized I could register for google web master tools.
not sure if it's worth.
any feedback would be welcome

Comment: Might have better/more responses from Serverfault.com or Superuser.com...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google webmaster tools is more about your site and how google looks at it with its search engine.
You can configure things like crawl access, rate and view your sites loading speed and possible crawl errors.

And analytics as you know is about your visitors.

Comment: I think so, because it shows you how to optimise your website for google. it's free, why don't you try?